# My Android app shows Admob interstitial Test ads but not real ads

Tags: android, admob, build.gradle, google-play-services, androidx

My Android app shows Admob interstitial Test ads but not real ads . i tried many solutions before posting this question. but i cant find any answer to be working.
also i tried with the new ads ID. ( Waited for 2 weeks still nothing ... )
and Test ads work perfectly fine.

i guess the problem is here in build.gradle app

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxx.yyyyy"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 27
        buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'

}
```

i tried to migrate to AndroidX . still not working and many errors ...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxx.yyyyy"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0'

}
```

Comment: It seems reasonable that show test ad in debug version. Have you check the `AdmobId` and tried to build in release version?

Comment: please capture logs and update in your question

Answer (score 0):

setup your device as a test device. check [this](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9691433) to setup a test device.
if you are using emulator it is already set as a test device.
use test id to test Ads.
use your original App Id and Ad Id only if you want to publish the app.
make sure your Ad mod account does not have any sort of limit(like Account being assessed, Ad serving is limited).